# buffernext is distorting the window layout

Tags: vim, buffer, vim-plugin

I've been using `:bnext` to jump to to the next buffer in the buffer list (among
all hidden buffers). However, whenever I issue the "buffer next" command, there
are two circumstances:

1. If I were in the `:only` mode, i.e. there is only one buffer per
   window, that is fine. The previous buffer become hidden and `:bnext` will bring
   me the next buffer up front.
2. If I were having two buffers up and had arranged them through `:vsplit`,
   still, switching is fine. The new buffer will pop up at the left panel
   (vertically spliced)
3. If I were having two buffers up and have arrange them through `:split`, i.e.
   two buffers is laid out one on top of the other, I will have trouble. Issuing
   `:bnext` will distort the buffer layout of the window by bringing the new buffer
   to the left, and have the two buffers vertically split.

Is there a global setting that I can turn on to administrate the action taken by
the `:bnext`? I am looking for a way to switch to the next buffer without
distilling all my current buffer layout.

(Note that, this distortion gets worse when I have more than two buffers shown
on the screen/session. In that case, `:bnext` will squeeze all the previous
buffers to the right, and occupy a vertical panel alone.)

Does this look familiar to you? Hope you could help me with this.

All the best,

-Linfeng

Comment: Well, I found that it is one of my plugin that is callusing the trouble. It is `dwm.Vim`, which handles the "primary buffer" and tunes the width of the panels of vertically split windows. 

Turning it off completely will solve the problem I've just discussed.

Comment: This is not the default behavior. You probably want to disable any plugins to figure out if the problem is with one of them. You may also want to check any customization with your `~/.vimrc` file

Comment: @PeterRincker: You are absolutely correct. I've found the plugin that causes the wired behavior. Thank you.

Comment: Please post an answer to your question with what plugin was causing the problem and how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.

```
dwm.vim
```

is the plug-in that causes the problem. It tries to make the buffer that it switches to the "main buffer", which is be default lying on the left of the screen, occupying the whole panel length.

Answer (score 0):

Update on solution at the `dwm.vim` side:

Solution had been offered by TimoDritschler in the following thread: 
https://github.com/spolu/dwm.vim/issues/62#issuecomment-73743583

A "ready-to-go" dwm distribution of mine could be found at: 
https://github.com/llinfeng/dwm.vim/

With the update, the main "compartment" of the window will not be occupied by the buffer that we switch to. Moreover, pressing `<C-@>` will send the current active buffer (the one with flashing cursor) to the "main compartment". It seems that nothing had been lost and stability had been gained.

Many thanks to [TimoDritschler](https://github.com/TimoDritschler) on Github again!